# Parallel vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: vectors

**Definition:** We say that $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are parallel vectors if $|\vec{x}\cdot \vec{y}| = \|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{y}\|$. (i.e equality holds in Cauchy–Schwarz inequality)

I'm having some problems showing that if $\vec{x},\vec{y}$ are parallel vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then one is a scalar multiple of the other.

Comment: Hint: If you are working in R^n then you have a set of basis vectors.  Try to express both x and y in that basis and mull that over for a bit.  It should shed some light on your problem.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the angle between vectors?

Comment: Sorry @unclejamil,Could you be more explicit? I can't see how it might work.

Comment: And @MichaelAlbanese I just know the formula for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: It also works for $\mathbb{R}^n$, namely $|x\cdot y| = \|x\|\|y\|\cos\theta$. One way to prove the claim is to use this formula.

Comment: Didn't know that, but still @MichaelAlbanese don't see how to use it!

Comment: As far as I know it is _part of the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality)_ that equality only holds if the vectors are linearly dependent, which is what you are asking about. Just look up the proof of C-S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we usually restrict the notion of parallel vectors to *non-zero* vectors.

Recall that for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, $|x\cdot y| = \|x\|\|y\|\cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $y$. If $x$ and $y$ are parallel, then $|x\cdot y| = \|x\|\|y\|$, so $\cos\theta = 0$. Therefore $\theta = 0$, in which case $x$ are $y$ are pointing in the same direction, or $\theta = \pi$, in which case they are pointing in opposite directions. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assume $x\neq0$.  A quick calculation reveals that the length of the vector
$$y-\frac{x\cdot y}{\|x\|^2}x$$
equals $0$ provided that $|x\cdot y|=\|x\|\|y\|$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = \|x\|n$ where $n$ is the unit vector in the direction of $x$. Now if $y$ is parallel to $x$ they must have same support, that is $y = \pm \|y\|n$ sub unit vector we get $y = (\text{scalar})\,x$.

Comment: please make use of MathJax (LaTeX) and explain your notation